# Are there analytical methods to efficiently minimize multivariable functions with a large number of variables?

Tags: analysis, optimization

Say I have a function with ~100 variables that I want to minimize. Are there analytical methods to achieve this, or do I have to stick to iterative algorithms such as gradient descent or quasi-newtonian methods?

Comment: That very much depends on the exact details of your system. If everything is just second-degree / quadratic, for instance, then there aren't any real hurdles to analytic solving other than sheer amount of work, you just differentiate and solve.

Comment: Convex? Non-convex? Linear? Quadratic? Polynomial? Non-polynomial?